# Webdriver: Firefox driver doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I created webdriver project with maven. Everything was fine, but one day my tests throw an exception while they running in Firefox. My Firefox version is 11 at this moment.

In my pom file i tried to change versions, but tests still don't work:
-Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. 
Or
-Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.

Please, help with this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using Firefox 3.6, 9 or 10, because WebDrivers 2.19.0 and 2.20.0 (today's version) are not yet compatible with Firefox 11.

[The official changelog](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) says that version 2.19.0 enables native events in FF10. Also, the version 2.15.0 announces support for FF up to and including FF11. Seems that something got wrong there :). Downgrade to FF10 or similar and you should be good.

Comment: This is happening to me too; it seems to be the problem of the day. This behavior started after Firefox updated itself to V11.0. Most people don't set out to use a particular version of Firefox (or Chrome) they just let it keep itself up to date. Mostly this is a good thing to do. But not in this case.

Comment: Yeah. I guess for testing purposes, it is a good thing to have multiple browsers... =/

Comment: It works!!! Also i had problems with selenium version in my pom file. Now it' ok.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Selenium WebDriver 2.25.0 and my tests worked again.

Comment: At this time, FF 13 is supported. but I am having a similar issue with FF 14-15

Comment: There is a bug with webdriver in 2.25.0, so if you are using this, be sure to include selenium-server in your dependency too. See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4314 for more info.